# How to delete an image in docker by its number, which one is it?

Tags: docker

What went wrong here, this is what I've tried:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
784e80e16c2e        72e102fd1a20        "flask run"         14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:8085->5000/tcp   clickcounter
# it is flask not clickcounter

$ docker rmi flask
Error: No such image: flask

$ docker rm 72
Error: No such container: 72

$ docker rm 78
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 784e80e16c2e4482026180f73706beecab4619f53164213c004e41068ced6bde. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

$ docker stop 72
Error response from daemon: No such container: 72

$ docker stop 78
78

$ docker rmi 78
Error: No such image: 78

# why that??
```

When do I need which of these numbers for? I surely pick the wrong item but how to identify which column for which task.

Answer (score 0):

`78` or `clickcounter` are correct for `docker rm` and `docker stop`. This is the container ID/name

`72` is correct for `rmi` since it is the image ID.

You'd use `docker images` to show images, not `docker ps -a`, and you cannot remove an image non-forcibly with a running container